# How to create multiple loop in archive page?

Tags: wordpress

This is my archive page codes

i want to avoid duplicate posts in 4th loop & i want to count post in 3rd loop

there are 4 loops

1 first loop count : 1 post

```
  <?php 
  $count = 1;
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();            
  if($count == 1) : ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

2 second loop - - count = 1 post

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 2) : ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?>  </a>
```

3  third loop-- count = 5 post

```
<?php else : ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<h1>Most Viewed News</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

4  loop -- count = rest of all post

```
<?php else : ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

-- ad count --

```
<?php if ( $count == 3 || $count == 5 ) : ?>
<?php dt_show_ads();?> 
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?> 
<?php $count++; ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?> 


<?php else : ?>
<div class="post">
<h2 class="archiveTitle"><?php _e('Sorry','linepress');?></h2>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicate posts in the loop , you can set the loop posts in array and use in_array function to check if the post has looped or not .

```
<?php 

$do_not_duplicate = array ();

// first loop .
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_id();
    echo "<a href='LINK'>TITLE</a>"; 
  endwhile;
endif;

// 2nd loop .
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if ( !in_array ( get_the_id() , $do_not_duplicate ) ) {
       echo "<a href='LINK'>TITLE</a>"; 
       $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_id();
    }
  endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: attach the file here and I will modify for you .

Comment: here is file http://pastebin.com/Cbg95nDY . thanks a lot for your help 
you can see there are duplicate posts in archive page